# CSS font transition not working with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm using

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

p:hover {
    font-size: 20px;
```

}

```
<div class="parent">
   <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Transition when changing font size is not working as long as the parent has display flex. It works when removing the flex property. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: What browser are you using? This works fine in Chrome and Firefox for me: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7xwbqjw4/

Comment: unrelated but your missing the non-prefixed property for `transition` after the prefixed transition properties in your CSS rule.  `transition: all 0.3s ease;` Always best practice to have the non-prefixed CSS property after the prefixed properties in your CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in Firefox, Safari and Chrome and transition effect is working fine when font size is changing.

If it is not working for you, you can try adding display: -webkit-flex; along with display: flex; in your CSS code like this:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```